# Downloading Text from Several Links using WWW::Mechanize

Tags: perl, hyperlink, web-scraping, www-mechanize

For an entire week I have been attempting to write a code that will download links from a webpage and then loop through each link to dump the content written on each link's page. The original webpage I downloaded has 500 links to separate web pages that each contain important information for me. I only want to go one level down.  However I am having several issues.

RECAP: I want to download the links from a webpage and automatically have my program print off the text contained in those links. I would prefer to have them printed in a file.

1) When I download the links from the original website, the useful ones are not written out fully. (ie they say "/festevents.nsf/all?openform" which is not a usable webpage)

2) I have been unable to print the text content of the page. I have been able to print the font details, but that is useless.

```
     #Download all the modules I used#
     use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;
use HTML::FormatText;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use Data::Dumper;

#Download original webpage and acquire 500+ Links#

$url = "http://wx.toronto.ca/festevents.nsf/all?openform";

my $mechanize = WWW::Mechanize->new(autocheck => 1);

$mechanize->get($url);


my $title = $mechanize->title;

print "<b>$title</b><br />";


my @links = $mechanize->links;


foreach my $link (@links) {

   # Retrieve the link URL
   my $href = $link->url_abs;

  #
  # $URL1= get("$link");
  #
  my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
  my $response = $ua->get($href);
  unless($response->is_success) {
    die $response->status_line;
  }
  my $URL1 = $response->decoded_content;
  die Dumper($URL1);

#This part of the code is just to "clean up" the text
$Format=HTML::FormatText->new;
$TreeBuilder=HTML::TreeBuilder->new;
$TreeBuilder->parse($URL1);
$Parsed=$Format->format($TreeBuilder);

open(FILE, ">TorontoParties.txt");
print FILE "$Parsed";
close (FILE);

 }
```

Please help me! I am desperate! If possible please explain to me the logic behind each step? I have been frying my brain on this for a week and I want help seeing other peoples logic behind the problems.

Answer (score 1):

Too much work. Study the [WWW::Mechanize](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize) API to realise that almost all of that functionality is already built-in. Untested:

```
use strictures;
use WWW::Mechanize qw();
use autodie qw(:all);

open my $h, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', 'TorontoParties.txt';
my $mechanize = WWW::Mechanize->new;
$mechanize->get('http://wx.toronto.ca/festevents.nsf/all?openform');
foreach my $link (
    $mechanize->find_all_links(url_regex => qr'/festevents[.]nsf/[0-9a-f]{32}/[0-9a-f]{32}[?]OpenDocument')
) {
    $mechanize->get($link->url_abs);
    print {$h} $mechanize->content(format => 'text');
}
close $h;
```